# JRE bug? (Active directory authentication issue using kerberos)

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos

We have few active directory controllers and domains and our system should be able to query one domain using user from other domain.
We didn't mange to do it in java 1.60_00 because of a bug:

http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do;jsessionid=F6E8EB086BF9B51A61F4D441EC9DAFBD?noCount=true&externalId=KB33449&sliceId=2&cmd=displayKCPopup&docType=kc&isLoadPublishedVer=&docTypeID=DT_SUPPORTISSUE_1_1&ispopup=true&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl

Currently we have a problem with the following setup:
We are trying to connect to QA.DOM using administrator user of D200.D1.W2K8.CORP.ME and we get the following error:
"Mechanism level: Fail to create credential. (63) - No service creds".
We **can** connect to RESOURCE.W2K8.CORP.ME, we can also connect to QA.DOM if we are using D1.W2K8.CORP.ME's administrator.
    After investigating the pcap captures I think the java implementation has a bug regarding transitive trust to domains with different suffix.

BTW: we tried the same scenario with SMB based package written in C and it works. 
Is it known JRE bug (I searched java bug, and found nothing)?
Is a workaround exist?

Our active directory setup:

```
QA.DOM<----ForestTrust-->D1.W2K8.CORP.ME<-----ForestTrust--->RESOURCE.W2K8.CORP.ME
----------------------------------------------^
-----------------------------------------------|
-----------------------------------------------|
-----------------------------------------------|
-----------------------------------------------^
--------------------------------------------tree(two way trust)
----------------------------------------D200.D1.W2K8.CORP.ME (child of D1.W2K8.CORP.ME).
```

And the krb file:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = D200.D1.W2K8.CORP.ME
default_keytab_name = FILE:/usr/local/ctera/portal.keytab
[realms]
D200.D1.W2K8.CORP.ME = {
    kdc = D200.D1.W2K8.CORP.ME
}
D1.W2K8.CORP.ME = {
    kdc = D1.W2K8.CORP.ME
}
RESOURCE.W2K8.CORP.ME = {
    kdc = RESOURCE.W2K8.CORP.ME
}
QA.DOM = {
    kdc = QA.DOM
}
[domain_realm]
.d200.d1.w2k8.corp.me = D200.D1.W2K8.CORP.ME
d200.d1.w2k8.corp.me = D200.D1.W2K8.CORP.ME
.d1.w2k8.corp.me = D1.W2K8.CORP.ME
d1.w2k8.corp.me = D1.W2K8.CORP.ME
.resource.w2k8.corp.me = RESOURCE.W2K8.CORP.ME
resource.w2k8.corp.me = RESOURCE.W2K8.CORP.ME
.qa.dom = QA.DOM
qa.dom = QA.DOM
```

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the post.
I am asking if it is known JRE bug? and if a workaround exist?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are asking here.  However,

> We didn't mange to do it in java 1.60_00 because of a bug

There is no such version of Java.

If you are asking if you are experiencing the bug you linked to, the bug reports states that the (supposed) workaround is to revert to a version of Java 1.6 older than 1.6.0_31.  So if your version is already older than that, this is evidence that this is NOT your problem.

---

As to whether it is *some* JRE bug ...

Well if you Google for that error message, there are lots of hits.  And a quick read through some of them indicate that *a lot of the time* the root problem is with the way people have configured things.  So, if I were you I would pursue *that* theory first.

The other thing you could do (if you have an Oracle service contract) is open a ticket ...

Comment: To be clear:
in first version of java 6 we didn't manage to login to any of the active-directories.
in 1_60_39 we only have the issue I described.

Comment: Well that suggests to me that this the problem is not that JRE bug.

Comment: I also thought so, so we tested our setup with third party active directory tool (written in C) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a bug for oracle and they fixed it:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8012615